# Updating the fontsize only of title, xlabel or ylabel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that we have the following methods to add/change xlabel, ylabel and the title:

```
fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=20)
```

but if I don't want to change the actual string of any of these properties and I just want to change the fontsize?

If I try any of these functions with the fontsize argument alone, it won't work:

```
plt.xlabel(fontsize=20)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: xlabel() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: This is a good case for avoiding the `pyplot` interface. If you're acting on the `Axes` object directly, you can do `ax.set_xlabel("The text you want", fontsize=20)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `set_fontsize` method:

```
plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
plt.xlabel('To change it', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('To keep it', fontsize=20)
plt.gca().xaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(50)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. On this topic, how can I use `plt.gca().<>` to also change the font size of the xtick labels?

Comment: Also, does this work for the `title`? When I try plt.gca().title.get_lael()

Comment: It is doable, but you should consider avoiding `pyplot` as this point as it is becoming very unreadable: `plt.gca().set_xticklabels(map(str, plt.gca().get_xticks()), fontsize=15)` to change the ticks. For title you just need `plt.gca().title.set_fontsize(50)`

Answer (score 4):

Because I am feeling cranky about pyplot today:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)  # first use of pyplot to get the fig/ax objects
xlabel = ax.set_xlabel('test')
ax.set_ylabel('test2', fontsize=20)
xlabel.set_fontsize(25)

plt.draw()    # second use to make sure the gui re-draws it self
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get the current label, and set the whole thing again:

```
plt.xlabel(plt.gca().get_xlabel(), fontsize=20)
```

Comment: If would be far better to just grab the text object and change it's size.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xlabel#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel) you could do:

```
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 20}

plt.xlabel('xlabel', **font)
```

Comment: I believe this sets the x label to `'font'`.

Comment: @askewchan - Indeed it does. I changed it from the vanilla docs to the OP's label.

Answer (score 1):

`plt.xlabel`, IIRC, is going to set the `xlabel` of the current axes object. If you want to change properties of a label (or any text element) after creating it, you need to have it saved in a variable.

For example:

```
plt.subplots()
xlabel = plt.xlabel('test')
xlabel.set_fontsize(20)
```

Comment: it would be better to grab the reference to the axes instead of using pyplot

Comment: @tcaswell, I agree. I'm just trying to dial my anti-`pyplot` crusade down a bit :)

Comment: I see no reason to do so, crusade away!  It really seems to me 25% of the confusion about mpl has to do one way or another with the state machine in pyplot doing something surprising/only exposing a fraction of the functions (under slightly different names!).  The less examples floating around the internet using pyplot the better.